# Excel VBA range.find acting up

Tags: vba, excel, visual-studio-macros

Im trying to use range.find to look up a value within a column, and return the matching value from the next column.

I recorded the find() using the macro recorder, which seemed to work fine for a while, but for some reason it's now giving me an error. As far as I can tell I haven't changed anything that should affect this bit of code.

This is what I have

```
Public Function look_up_id(id, table)
    Worksheets(table).Activate
    Cells.Find(What:=id, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    look_up_id = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End Function
```

The error I'm now getting is:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Any idea why this is now happening?

All the resources I can find on range.find() look like I'm doing it right...

Cheers - David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Public Function look_up_id(id, table) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    look_up_id = "Not Found"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(table)

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:=id, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then _
        look_up_id = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    End With
End Function
```

More on `.Find` [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this code instead (when `Find` doesn't find anything, it returns `Nothing` and then you tried to do sth like this `Nothing.Activate`, and this triggers an error):

```
Dim res As Range

Set res = Worksheets(table).Cells.Find(What:=id, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not res Is Nothing Then
    look_up_id = res.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.

What exactly was it that you changed that was causing my error?

Comment: I aplly the result of `Find` to the `res` variable. Then I check whether the `res` is `Nothing` (if it is, `Find` doesn't find anything), If it isn't `Nothing`, function returns desired value

Comment: How exactly are you offsetting a Nothing?