# VBA Run time error 91. Trouble setting object variable debug

Tags: vba

I have taken over someone else's macro who has left the organisation. I get the following error as listed in the title with Run time error.

Below is the code it is telling me to debug. Problem is this is my first time to VBA macro's and I am unsure where to begin to solve the error.

Any help would be great as I can't go past this point.

```
Cells.Find(What:="Top 10 Rank", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
       SearchDirection:= xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
       SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA range.find acting up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403916/excel-vba-range-find-acting-up)

Answer (score 1):

If the value is not found in the search range then you will get an error, so it's best to split up your code into separate operations:

```
Dim f As Range
Set f = Cells.Find(What:="Top 10 Rank", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:= xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                   SearchFormat:=False)

If Not f Is nothing Then
    'do somthing with f
Else
    Msgbox "not found!"
End If
```

Comment: @MarkMeiring on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) the best "thank you" is a checkmark. See that green checkmark icon under the up/down voting buttons? Give it some lovin', you'll get +2 for it and tell the world "this! this right here, look! this is the answer!"

Answer (score 1):

No data was found, so `.Find` returned a null object reference (`Nothing` in VBA), as explained in this [Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/108892):

> This macro error occurs because the Visual Basic Find method returns a NULL value which makes activating a cell impossible.